# Apache add subdomain

Tags: apache-http-server, virtual-host, subdomain

I need to add a subdomain to [this](http://login.acorn.lt) server, i added this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName images.login.acorn.lt
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName login.acorn.lt
</VirtualHost>
```

config to `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and restarted with `apachectl -k graceful` , without error. But images.login.acorn.lt is down

Comment: Which effect do you expect? Both virtual hosts have the same document root. They will show the same content.

Comment: images.login.acorn.lt doesn't work at all, i added same root just for the test @Matteo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have `images.login.acorn.lt` to work you have to assign the same IP as `login.acorn.lt` (they have both to point to your address).

At the moment `images.login.acorn.lt` is not registered.

```
$ host login.acorn.lt
login.acorn.lt has address 79.98.30.58
$ host images.login.acorn.lt
Host images.login.acorn.lt not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Comment: so how do i get it to do that?

Comment: By your DNS registrar. In the same way you registered login.acorn.lt

Answer (score 1):

You have register your custom sub-domain name with dns registrar to make it it working. I mean
you need a valid DNS record for your subdomain too. You can accomplish this by either setting up an individual DNS entry for each new subdomain, But every namebasedvirtualhost has to have a valid DNS entry. Moreover custom domain name must be allowed on server.For Custom sudomain domain name you have to specify and register proper dns.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: improved the answer @Fazer87

Comment: Much better :)  Generally people are asking for help because they dont know how or why.  Just answering HOW may not help them or others in the long run

Comment: got it...might be upvoted now :)